# expectation of distribution where arguments are distributions too

Tags: probability-theory, expectation, variance

I want to find an expectation and variance of `c`, where

$ c | a, b  \sim Poiss(0.5 a + 0.05 b) $

$ a \sim R(15, 30) $

$ b \sim R(250, 350) $

Where `R` is uniform distribution, `Poiss` is Poisson distribution.

Should I use expectation of `a` and `b` to find expectation of `c` or it would be wrong?

Comment: Are we to assume that $a$ and $b$ are independent random variables?

Comment: yes, $a$ and $b$ are independent and random, but $c$ depends on both $a$ and $b$ and random (with Poisson law) too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** You can use conditional expectations. Since $c$ is conditionally Poisson, we have $\mathbb{E}(c\mid a,b)=.5a+.05b.$ It follows that 
$$\mathbb{E}(c)=\mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}(c\mid a,b))=\mathbb{E}(.5a+.05b).$$
Similarly, 
$$\mathbb{E}(c^2)=\mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}(c^2\mid a,b))=\mathbb{E}\left((.5a+.05b)(.5a+.05b+1)\right).$$
We  use the fact that if $X$ is Poisson($\lambda$), then $\mathbb{E}(X)=\lambda$ and  $\mathbb{E}(X^2)=\lambda(\lambda+1)$.